# what is meant by that in a servlet (private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L)?

Tags: java

Can any one tell me that what is the meaning of

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

Comment: I'd say it's a different question but still the answer i the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)