# Static Final Long serialVersionUID = 1L

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)
>   [what is meant by that in a servlet (private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335768/what-is-meant-by-that-in-a-servlet-private-static-final-long-serialversionuid)

I have 1 simple question about this guided program given by our professor. 
I have seen serialVersionUID several times but I dont what's that for.

```
package module;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * @author JA
 */
public class Servlet_1 extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet{

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("txt/html");

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>Hello Panget</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello Panget</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            // Write your program here, Panget.
    }
}
```

What is the use of `static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;` in the program?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The `serialVersionUID` is a universal version identifier for a `Serializable` class. Deserialization uses this number to ensure that a loaded class corresponds exactly to a serialized object. If no match is found, then an `InvalidClassException` is thrown.