# serialVersionUID without L, xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxL vs 1L, positive vs negative

Tags: java, serialization, jdk1.7

I read [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it) and [static final long serialVersionUID = 1L](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274480/static-final-long-serialversionuid-1l). From these two SO posts I have a rough idea of what it is. It is an ID for a Serializable class used to check if the sender and receiver are compatible during deserialization. If not a `InvalidClassException` is thrown.

However I am curious about a few things:

- `serialVersionUID` seems to be divided into 2 "type". 19 numbers followed by L xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxL or 269L or 1L. These numbers don't seem arbitrarily chosen. If we simply need an ID wouldn't any number work? what is the logic behind this design.
- For the 20 characters long `serialVersionUID` it can be positive or negative. What is the difference. Again if `serialVersionUID` is used for the purpose of identifying, why do we need to have a negative number? We have not used up all the positive numbers yet.
- In `MirroredTypedException.java` the `serialVersionUID` is 269 without the `L`. It is the only `serialVersionUID` I found without the `L`. Why is that? What is the meaning of `L`?

a snapshot (this snapshot doesn't include all of them)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> serialVersionUID seems can be divide into 2 "type"

Not really. They're all just `long`s.

> For the 20 characters long serialVersionUID it can be positive or negative.

These are all just randomly chosen. If you randomly choose a number between `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE` then most of the time it will have 19 digits, and half the time it will be negative.

Sometimes they might be generated from a hash of something (e.g. sourcecode, an xml definition, etc.). If the hash function is any good, then the distribution of numbers will be the same as if just choosing randomly.

> Why is that? What is the meaning of L?

[`L` identifies a literal of type `long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). It's not needed for `269`, because it fits in the range of `int`, and will be automatically upcast to a `long`.